# Can't get dropdownlist to bind to an array being returned from my service

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I have a service that contains a method that gets a list of employees:

```
export class EmployeeService {

    private employeesUrl = 'http://localhost:portnum/api/employees';


    getEmployees(): Observable<IEmployee[]> {
        return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this.employeesUrl).catch(this.errorHandler);
    }
}
```

In my Component, I have this snippet which fetches the list of employees from my service:

```
employees = [];

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private _employeeService: EmployeeService) {
    this.transactionForm = fb.group ({
      'employee': [null, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(data => this.employees = data, error => this.errorMsg = error);
  }
```

and in my html code, I have a dropdownlist that binds to list of employees:

```
<span style="padding-right:60px;">{{'Employee' | translate}}*
          <select [ngModel]="null" formControlName="employee" [ngClass]="displayErrors ? 'inputRedBorder': 'input'" required >
            <option value="null" disabled selected>{{'SelectEmployee' | translate}}</option>
            <option *ngFor="let employee of employees">{{employee}}</option>
        </select>
        <p class="error-msg" *ngIf="displayErrors" name="errorMsg">
            {{'RequiredField' | translate}}</p>
    </span>
```

However, instead of having a dropdownlist showing all the employees returned, I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
    at DefaultIterableDiffer.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js.DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.js:7495)
    at NgForOf.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/common.js.NgForOf.ngDoCheck (common.js:2583)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12368)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13889)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13832)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14725)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14666)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (TransactionPortalComponent.html:23)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14651)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13798)
```

The object is an array, so I'm not sure why it says only arrays and iterables are allowed. What am I doing wrong above?

EDIT:

Response from api should look like this:

```
{
    _employeeList :
    [{
        _employeeKey : ""employee1""
    },
    {
        _employeeKey : ""employee2""
    }],
   _errorDetails :
   {
        _message : ""successful"",
       _status : 200
   }
}
```

But I am only getting back [] array.

Could it be related to my interface? :

```
export interface IEmployee {
    employee: string;
}
```

Comment: Could you please do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.employees))` after subscribing to the service and post the output here?

Comment: @edkeveked I get [] as output in the console. Just an empty array. So this means it could be an api data issue? In cases with empty arrays, how best should I handle it?

Comment: Maybe you can use the `*ngIf` directive before starting your loop. Consider my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you are doing the loop is wrong, since you want to have a tag `<option>` for each employee.

Also, since your array might be empty, you can first check if the array contains data or not. Maybe you can consider using `<ng-template>` and `ng-container`.

With this response coming from your api, you have to make the following changes:

**service**

The api is returning a JSON and not an array

```
getEmployees(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(this.employeesUrl).catch(this.errorHandler);
    }
```

**component**

Get the array

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(data => this.employees = data._employeeList, error => this.errorMsg = error);
  }
```

**template**

Since you want to display not the object itself but its value, you can do the following:

```html
 <ng-container *ngIf="employees?.length>0">
  <ng-template ngFor let-employee [ngForOf]="employees">
   <option>{{employee._employeeKey}}</option>
  </ng-template>
 </div>
```

Comment: create the form INTO subscription function

Comment: The response I should be getting is in this format: https://pastebin.com/F3jrYFpS I'm wondering if it's related to how I set up my interface? I will edit my post

Comment: Thank you so much. It was an issue with the json object format and you're right, for the template, I need to add _employeeKey to bind to the correct field. Thanks a lot for your help! In the future though, should I create an interface that matches the json and make it strongly typed?

Comment: I come from javaScript background, so honestly even if I like the typing of TypeScript I don't like to much restricting myself with it. So It is much a matter of preference I would say. You have to do as you see fit :)

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you have injected your service as _employeeService, but in your ngOnInit() method you are calling this._transactionService.getEmployees(). It should be this._employeeService.getEmployees().

Comment: sorry, not the issue. I had to rename some things for this SO post. I fixed the typo but I'm still having the issue.

Comment: It looks to me like your data is coming back as objects, hence the [Object Object] error. Your HTML binding is looking for employee.someProp, but you aren't binding to an object property. Have you consoled out your data in the ngOnInit method to see that it's coming back correctly?

Comment: It became an empty array [] when I output to console

Comment: In your span tag you can do *ngIf="employees" if you want to catch an empty array and not show the dropdown. Then you could put in an additional div or something with *ngIf="!employees" if you want to show something like "No employees found!". Looks like you could have an api bug somewhere if you're getting back an empty array.